# Css or Xpath selector can't select a list element

Tags: python, selenium, rpa

I am trying to automate a process on a website that dynamically generates IDs for its elements :

Ids have this form:
    ZCODE:FORM:j_1279323:element

I managed to make CSS or XPATH selectors for most of the elements. 
I am struggling though with a `ul/li` element which I manage to click on with its `id` but not with a relative XPath, which is what I aim to achieve:

I have tried all sorts of xpath:
    `/html[1]/body/[1]/div[37]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[13]`

also:
    `//div[contains(@id, 'voie_panel')]/div/ul/li[13]`

And many other different ways..
All the xpath/css selector I tested work perfectly in chrome developer console.

I only manage to drop the list down, but when I am trying to access the list element... it times-out.

I am using `WebDriverWait`, I have also tried to Pause the program at the exact point where it has to be loaded in order to click on the list.

I wait for the element with:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((BY.XPATH, css))
```

To summarize the situation :
It works smoothly with the ID but times out with an xpath or css selector

Can someone recommend a strategy to overcome this ?

Comment: can you share your `html` code

Comment: Any XPath that starts with `/html` is definitely going to be brittle / unreliable. Your code `ec.element_to_be_clickable((BY.XPATH, css)` looks suspicious, but without more context we have no way of knowing. Locator strategies are discussed here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#location-strategies

Comment: I'll get back to it next tuesday thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using selenium web driver you can add this to your code

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    scpathTemp = str(scpathTemp).replace('/', '\\').strip()
    preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": True}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=master_path + "/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body/[1]/div[37]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[13]").click()
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation about what this code actually accomplishes, and how it helps to OP.